# How to export asynchronously loaded data to be used in a different node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, configuration-files

I have an issue with loading config variables which are loaded by async call.

the config variables like the following:

```
//config.js
let config = {
    db: {
        dev: {
            client: ENV_VARS.dev_db_client,
            host: ENV_VARS.dev_db_host,
            name: ENV_VARS.dev_db_name,
            user: ENV_VARS.dev_db_user,
            password: ENV_VARS.dev_db_password,
            min_pool: ENV_VARS.dev_db_min_pool,
            max_pool: ENV_VARS.dev_db_max_pool
        },
        staging: {
            client: ENV_VARS.staging_db_client,
            host: ENV_VARS.staging_db_host,
            name: ENV_VARS.staging_db_name,
            user: ENV_VARS.staging_db_user,
            password: ENV_VARS.staging_db_password,
            min_pool: ENV_VARS.staging_db_min_pool,
            max_pool: ENV_VARS.staging_db_max_pool
        },
        production: async function () {
            let secret = await getSecretFromStore(`SECRET_NAME`);
            let tmpConfig = JSON.parse(secret);
            return {
                    client: ENV_VARS.production_db_client,
                    host: tmpConfig.host,
                    password: tmpConfig.password,
                    user: tmpConfig.username,
                    name: tmpConfig.db_name,
                    min_pool: ENV_VARS.production_db_min_pool,
                    max_pool: ENV_VARS.production_db_max_pool
                };
            });
    },
    NODE_ENV: ENV_VARS.NODE_ENV,
    STACK_ID: ENV_VARS.STACK_ID,
};
module.exports = config;

//knexfile.js
const config = require('authenticator/config');
let productionConfig = {};
if (config.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
// how to load the production vars in the right way and export them?
//the next line is async call and it is wrong to call it like this
    productionConfig = config.db.production();
}
const _config = {
    development: {
        client: config.db.dev.client,
        connection: {
            host: config.db.dev.host,
            database: config.db.dev.name,
            user: config.db.dev.user,
            password: config.db.dev.password,
            // debug: ['ComQueryPacket']
        },
        pool: {
            min: Number(config.db.dev.min_pool) || 0,
            max: Number(config.db.dev.max_pool) || 1
        },
        migrations: {
            tableName: 'knex_migrations'
        }
    },

    staging: {
        client: config.db.staging.client,
        connection: {
            host: config.db.staging.host,
            database: config.db.staging.name,
            user: config.db.staging.user,
            password: config.db.staging.password
        },
        pool: {
            min: Number(config.db.staging.min_pool) || 0,
            max: Number(config.db.staging.max_pool) || 1
        },
        migrations: {
            tableName: 'knex_migrations'
        }
    },

    production: {
        client: productionConfig.client,
        connection: {
            host: productionConfig.host,
            database: productionConfig.name,
            user: productionConfig.user,
            password: productionConfig.password
        },
        pool: {
            min: Number(productionConfig.min_pool) || 0,
            max: Number(productionConfig.max_pool) || 1
        },
        migrations: {
            tableName: 'knex_migrations'
        }
    }
};
module.exports = _config;
//db.js
const config = require('config');
//the config are loaded into knexfile.js and used but production can't be loaded cuz it is async call
//the next line should call the production vars in the env is production
const knexConfig = require('../knexfile')[config.NODE_ENV];
const knex = require('knex')(knexConfig);
module.exports = knex;
```

So, is there any good strategy to load that module in different node_module?

in another word, it is easy to load staging and dev variables and use them, but since the production variables are loaded by async call, then how to load them in the right way?

If generators are used. will this solve the issue?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I will update the code

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see it, in the `config.js`stuff.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've updated the code to load the complete components

Comment: Why does the module export configs for all environments, instead of just for the active environment? That complicates things.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I will be really great full if you can give me some tips about how can I solve the issue. The config.js has all the config variables and I can export the required env config by choosing for example config.db.production

Comment: I'm trying, but again, why export all the configs?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is to choose the required config by choosing which stage I need. like require('config').db.production

Comment: Again: *Why*? Then you're having to use `config.NODE_DEV`/`ENV_VARS.NODE_ENV` everywhere. Why not centralize that logic to this module? Have it return a config relevant to the current environment?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I get your idea. the config part should be improved. if the config is loaded by an async call, then what is the right way to export them?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is make the development and staging config have the same semantics as live. Since `production` returns a promise, `dev` and `staging` should return a promise as well. Not doing so is setting yourself up for surprises going to production.

So for instance:

```
db: {
    dev: async function() {
        await delay(0); // Where `delay` is a `setTimeout` wrapper
        return {
            client: ENV_VARS.dev_db_client,
            host: ENV_VARS.dev_db_host,
            name: ENV_VARS.dev_db_name,
            user: ENV_VARS.dev_db_user,
            password: ENV_VARS.dev_db_password,
            min_pool: ENV_VARS.dev_db_min_pool,
            max_pool: ENV_VARS.dev_db_max_pool
        };
    },
// ....
```

...and the same for staging. You might even see how long the delay is in production and mimic that in `dev` and `staging`. (Unless you're returning all configs as you currently are.)

Your `production` should also be an `async` function, since you're using `await` within it.

Your next step is to de-duplicate that code. You have the same structure being built for all three configs; centralize that in a function:

```
function buildConfig(env) {
    return {
        client: env.client,
        connection: {
            host: env.host,
            database: env.name,
            user: env.user,
            password: env.password,
            // debug: ['ComQueryPacket']
        },
        pool: {
            min: Number(env.min_pool) || 0,
            max: Number(env.max_pool) || 1
        },
        migrations: {
            tableName: 'knex_migrations'
        }
    };
}
```

Then, export a promise of the configs, not the actual configs:

```
module.exports = Promise.all([config.db.dev, config.db.staging, config.db.production])
    .then(([dev, staging, production]) => {
        return {
            development: buildConfig(dev),
            staging:     buildConfig(staging),
            production:  buildConfig(production)
        };
    });
```

Modules using it will need to consume that promise, since the operation is async (in all environments):

```
require(/*...*/).then(config => {
    // Code using the config here...
});
```

---

Before that much longer, this will become less painful (with ESM modules, not CommonJS ones) thanks to the [top-level `await` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await), which lets module resolution be asynchronous and lets you use `await` at the top level.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try the idea. I have two questions here. 1. what is the right way or the best practice to write config provider for any high-level project? because I felt like you told me it is not the right way to load config in a project. 2. if I use the following approach to load the config. will the function that loads the config from the async store will be executed every time the project receive a request. or only one time(on loading the project)? I feel the second question is a bit silly but pls if you can answer me. Thanks

Comment: @ِAllloush - Glad that helped. 1. I don't have any special insight here. One thing, though, is I think a single `config` module should handle the environmental differences, so other modules don't have to. So I'd have `config` only export the config for the active env (dev, staging, or production), not all three. 2. What's exported is the result of calling the `async` functions (`dev`, `staging`, or `production`), which is a promise. It isn't something that calls the functions, it's the *result* of calling them. You can use that promise as many times as you like, it won't call the functions.

Comment: @ِAllloush - Normally you wouldn't use an async store (some http server or database table or memcache key-pair). The two most common way to load configs is using something like the `config` module (it allows you to commit a generic config file then override it in production) or if you're on a *nix system use something like the `rc` module (it implements standard unix config conventions like rc files (.myapprc) and configs in the /etc directory). Then you'd use configuration management tools like puppet or chef to manage configs (just like all your other configs: nginx/apache, iptables etc)